# Magento 2.1: Hide block when product collection is empty

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, blocks, product-collection

In Magento 2.1 I am trying to hide a specific block in the layout when the loaded product collection is empty. Is there a way to do it via XML or via PHP?

The container I would like to remove/hide is this:

```
<container name="div.sidebars" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-3 col-lg-2" before="main">
        <container name="div.sidebar.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-main">
            <container name="sidebar.main" as="sidebar_main" label="Sidebar Main"/>
        </container>
        <container name="div.sidebar.additional" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-additional" after="div.sidebar.main">
            <container name="sidebar.additional" as="sidebar_additional" label="Sidebar Additional"/>
        </container>
</container>
```

Comment: is it your own block or from third party ?

Comment: it is not a thirdy party block

Comment: if its your own custom block then you can override toHtml method otherwise you will need to use plugins

Comment: can you give me the name of path to block you want to remove if its from magento. so i can find best solution

Comment: it is the "div.sidebars" container that I would like to hide/remove

Comment: Can u please share code of block class

Comment: see my edited answer

Comment: I am tasking about the block class where have the collection code

Comment: I have no block in which I have the collection. I was wondering if there is a way, via XML or PHP, to remove that container when the category I am showing has no products.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer is basic of idea

In magento, you can block block output  using **`view_block_abstract_to_html_before`.**

Create **events.xml** at *app/code/[Vendorname]/[ModuleName]/etc/frontend* for ***define an observer for those event***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="view_block_abstract_to_html_before">
        <observer name="ChangeatBlock" instance="[Vendorname]\[ModuleName]\Observer\ChangeatBlockContent" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Then observer class  change the out of block**

```
<?php
namespace [Vendorname]\[ModuleName]\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ChangeatBlockContent implements ObserverInterface
{

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){
        $block = $observer->getBlock();
        if($block->getNameInLayout() == '[YourBlockclassNameInLayout]'){
             if($block->[YOURCOLLECTIONFUNCTION]->getSize()<1){
              return '';
             }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: How do I know if the collection it is going to shown is empty?

Comment: So, you need check  to check every  block class which have a  diff production collection method. So.. you need to find out that mehod  and  use $collection->getSize() for getting collection size then it value is  less than one then you return  ` return '';`

Comment: Doing in this way, the container I am looking is never found

Comment: Not sure if i want to implement this. Wouldnt this create to much calls? Since you are checking every single block that is outputted on page load? i feel like there has to be a better way

Comment: I want to retract my upvote as this is just bad. You can easily put an aroundToHtml plugin function on the block class of your choosing and under certain conditions return nothing and else return $proceed();

Answer (score 0):

You can try from Controller by below code:

```
$layout = $this->getLayout();
$blockname="blockname";
$layout->unsetElement($blockname);
```

Comment: in which controller should I put it? I would like to remove the block on the category view page

Comment: then you can put category view controller by  overriding this.